# Fail fast if a Spring application cannot connect to its config server

Tags: java, spring

Consider you have a Spring application that gets its configuration from a config server. If it cannot connect to the config server, the application will continue to start but as all configurations are missing, it will eventually fail with a potentially misleading error.

Is it possible to configure Spring, so it immediately aborts when it cannot connect to its config server during startup?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `spring.cloud.config.failFast` to `true` in your `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties` file. Also, you can add `-Dspring.cloud.config.failFast=true` to the JVM arguments.

From the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#config-client-fail-fast)

> ### Config Client Fail Fast
>
> In some cases, it may be desirable to fail startup of a service if it cannot connect to the Config Server. If this is the desired behavior, set the bootstrap configuration property `spring.cloud.config.failFast=true` and the client will halt with an Exception.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve that by using spring cloud `Spring Cloud Config Server`and `Spring Cloud Config Client` components.

**1. Spring Cloud Config Server**

The Server provides an HTTP, resource-based API for external configuration (name-value pairs, or equivalent YAML content). The server is easily embeddable in a Spring Boot application using the @EnableConfigServer annotation. So this app is a config server:

```
//ConfigServer.java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

**2. Spring Cloud Config Client**

A Spring Boot application can take immediate advantage of the Spring Config Server (or other external property sources provided by the application developer), and it will also pick up some additional useful features related to Environment change events.

Then in the config client side you can configure fail fast by setting the bootstrap configuration property `spring.cloud.config.failFast=true`

Spring cloud documentation [Config Client Fail Fast](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#config-client-fail-fast)