# Spring Cloud Config Server on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

I have two microservices. A Spring Cloud Config Server and another module that implements Spring Cloud Config Client. When I use the default configuration for the Spring Cloud Config Server service (`localhost:8888`) I can start it locally without any issues, after which I can start my other module as well, using a `bootstrap.yml`, it clearly finds the Config Server, fetches its properties and starts properly. All good. Now I'd like to push both of these services to Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

The Config Server service works just fine, service is up and running in my Space, and using the browser I can verify that it can still fetch the property files from the specific GitHub repository.

The problem is the other module, the client. I've replaced the default `localhost:8888` in its `bootstrap.yml` file (`spring.cloud.config.url parameter`) to the now active service in the cloud using the Route bound to it and tried to start it locally. Unfortunately now it simply timeouts during startup. At this point I tried to specify longer timeouts but nothing helps.
Interesting thing is that if I directly copy the URL from the logs that timeouts I see it works properly in the browser locally. So why not in IntelliJ when I try to package the client with the changed parameter?

Sorry, I can't include much details here, but I hope maybe there is a straightforward solution that I've missed. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using OSS Spring Cloud Config Server or are you using Tanzu Spring Cloud Services? The difference is that with OSS SCC you would be building both the client & server & pushing both apps. With Tanzu SCC, you're creating a service through the marketplace (i.e. `cf marketplace`). You then only need to bind the service to your app and use the Tanzu SCC client libraries in your application.

Comment: This is my dependency:
`<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId><artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId></dependency>`

Otherwise I'm aware that adding this as a Service is a more typical approach but I wanted to run my own implementation for a reason: have an explicit microservice and simply have my other services find and talk to it as it is running in the background in the same PCF Space. Is this really not possible regardless of which API I'm using?

Comment: I would suggest you set this on your client. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40511256/1585136. It isn't going to solve the problem, but it often makes the underlying issues more apparent. What happens if you try `curl` or some other way to access the service? Do you perhaps have to access the service via an HTTP proxy from your local PC? Just a guess, but maybe your browser is set up with the proxy settings but your client app isnt.